# What is the default configuration used by gunicorn?

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

If for example, in the gunicorn startup, I do not set any config like worker_class or workers or even worker_connections, what configs will be used?

Comment: Have you tried just testing it by running it without any configs and seeing what happens?

Comment: It actually shows the worker class but not the workers amount..